# React-native eas-build failed android/ios on internal and production distribution

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, monorepo

I'm working on **Mac M1**
Expo sdk: **"^41.0.0"**
React-Native : **"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz"**
**eas-cli/0.22.0 darwin-x64 node-v15.14.0**
expo-cli: **"4.8.1"**

I'm trying to make a build with eas build but on android, I have this error on **run gradlew step**:

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/build/workingdir/build/packages/mobile/android/app/build.gradle' line: 87
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[stderr] > Could not read script '/build/workingdir/build/packages/mobile/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle' as it does not exist.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
[stderr] > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

and on ios this error **on the pod install** step:

```
Installing pods
Installing unimodules:
 expo-blur@9.0.3 from ../node_modules/expo-blur/ios
 expo-constants@10.1.3 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-crypto@9.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-crypto/ios
 expo-device@3.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-device/ios
 expo-font@9.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-linear-gradient@9.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios
 expo-localization@10.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-localization/ios
 expo-splash-screen@0.11.2 from ../node_modules/expo-app-loading/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
 expo-web-browser@9.1.0 from ../node_modules/expo-web-browser/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@2.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-core@7.1.1 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.2.2 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.1.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `greengot`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNCPicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, lottie-ios, lottie-react-native, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMFontInterface` depended upon by `UMReactNativeAdapter`
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
[stderr] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `30D024BF57B54856B3D80B20` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

I'm on a monorepo so like the documentation, I had try to symlink my modules with expo-yarn-workspaces like this:

```
 "expo-yarn-workspaces": {
    "symlinks": [
      "@unimodules/core",
      "@unimodules/react-native-adapter",
      "expo-app-loading",
      "expo-blur",
      "expo-constants",
      "expo-crypto",
      "expo-device",
      "expo-font",
      "expo-linear-gradient",
      "expo-localization",
      "expo-status-bar",
      "expo-web-browser",
      "unimodules-app-loader",
      "unimodules-task-manager-interface"
    ]
  },
```

when I remove this symlink, my android build failed :

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/build/workingdir/build/packages/mobile/android/app/build.gradle' line: 86
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[stderr] > Could not read script '/build/workingdir/build/packages/mobile/node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle' as it does not exist.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
[stderr] > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 28s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

and failed on ios too (on fastlane step) ...

```
❌  (ios/greengot/AppDelegate.h:2:9)

  1 | #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> 2 | #import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>
    |         ^ 'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found
  3 | #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
  4 | #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  5 | 
› Compiling greengot » main.m

❌  (ios/greengot/AppDelegate.h:2:9)

  1 | #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> 2 | #import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>
    |         ^ 'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found
  3 | #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
  4 | #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  5 | 
⚠️  Pods/boost-for-react-native: iOS@8.0 deployment version mismatch, expected >= 9.0 <= 14.4.99
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/greengot-brxnltnndsuntbcllfgoqfdowlsc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/greengot/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/greengot.build/Release-iphoneos/greengot.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/packages/mobile/ios/greengot/main.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

did you encounter these errors?
You know how to fix these mistakes?

Comment: facing exactly same issue. Did you find the solution?